# C++/CX - I need to pass a Platform::String into a method that takes a const char*?

Tags: c++, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm new to c++ (I'm a c# developer).

I have an SQLite wrapper class that requires you to pass in a database name as a `const char*` , however I only have it as a `Platform::String` (after doing a file search).

I cant seem to find a way to convert the `Platform::String` to `const char*`.

Ive seen another question on StackOverflow that explain why it isnt straight-forward, but no sample code or end-to-end solution.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: some help [C++/CLI in Action - Using interior and pinning pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17817/C-CLI-in-Action-Using-interior-and-pinning-pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know little about C++/CX, and I'm basing the answer on the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh755812.aspx).

The `String` class contains 16-bit Unicode characters, so you can't directly get a pointer to 8-bit `char`-typed characters; you'll need to convert the contents.

If the string is known to only contain ASCII characters, then you can convert it directly:

```
String s = whatever();
std::string narrow(s.Begin(), s.End());
function_requiring_cstring(narrow.c_str());
```

Otherwise, the string will need translating, which gets rather hairy. The following might do the right thing, converting the wide characters to multi-byte sequences of narrow characters:

```
String s = whatever();
std::wstring wide(s.Begin(), s.End());
std::vector<char> buffer(s.Length()+1);  // We'll need at least that much
for (;;) {
    size_t length = std::wcstombs(buffer.data(), wide.c_str(), buffer.size());
    if (length == buffer.size()) {
        buffer.resize(buffer.size()*2);
    } else {
        buffer.resize(length+1);
        break;
    }
}
function_requiring_cstring(buffer.data());
```

Alternatively, you may find it easier to ignore Microsoft's ideas about how strings should be handled, and use `std::string` instead.